# How to append the first element of a matrix onto a list over a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix, list-comprehension

I have two loops that runs for a different x and y coordinates and for each different (x,y) coordinates, a linear equation is being solved for force 1 and force 2 using matrices method i.e. finding the inverse of A if Ax = C. For each loop it gives an answer as a matrix where first element is force 1 and 2nd element is force 2 at those specific coordinates. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
def Force():
    Force1 = np.zeros((160,90))
    Force2 = np.zeros((160,90))
    for x in np.arange(0,16.1,0.1):
        for y in np.arange(1,9.1,0.1):
            l1 = np.hypot(x,y)
            l2 = np.hypot(15-x,y)
            A = np.array([[(x/l1),((x-15)/l2)],[(y/l1),(y/l2)]])
            c = np.array([[0],[70*9.81]])

            F = linalg.solve(A,c)
            Force1[x,y] = F[0]
            Force2[x,y] = F[1]
            print("Force 1 = {} \nForce 2 = {}\n".format(F[0], F[1]))
```

so at each point (x,y) a matrix [[Force 1],[Force 2]] is solved. Now I would like to append all the Force1(s) into a list of Force1[x,y] and similarly for Forces2(s) so that I can do

```
plt.imshow[Force1]
plt.imshow[Force2]
```

to plot a 2 heatmaps. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You mean 
mylistF1 = []  
mylistF2 = []  
mylistF1.append(Force1[x,y])
mylistF2.append(Force2[x,y])

??

Comment: If your final goal is to get 2 heatmaps, just use `plt.imshow(Force1)` and `plt.imshow(Force2)`.

Comment: I don't get your question, you already have your force arrays. Just type `plt.imshow(Force1)` for example.

Comment: I can't because it won't allow me, it gives me this error "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices" for Force1[x,y] = F[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves your issue - you were trying to assign to indices in `Force1` and `Force2` of type float. I've changed the for loops to use `enumerate` instead, and tweaked the assignment so it assigns `F[0][0]` and `F[1][0]`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
def Force():
    Force1 = np.zeros((160,90))
    Force2 = np.zeros((160,90))
    for i, x in enumerate(np.arange(0,16,0.1)):
        for j, y in enumerate(np.arange(1,9,0.1)):
            l1 = np.hypot(x,y)
            l2 = np.hypot(15-x,y)
            A = np.array([[(x/l1),((x-15)/l2)],[(y/l1),(y/l2)]])
            c = np.array([[0],[70*9.81]])

            F = linalg.solve(A,c)
            Force1[i, j] = F[0][0]
            Force2[i, j] = F[1][0]
#            print("Force 1 = {} \nForce 2 = {}\n".format(F[0], F[1]))
    plt.imshow(Force1)
    plt.show()
    plt.imshow(Force2)
    plt.show()

Force()
```

The generated plots are:

[image: Force 1]

and

[image: Force 2]